# BeautifulSoup doesn't reads tags properly

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am tring to parse an xml using BeautifulSOup, but it results in improper output.

file.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<opening name="value1" >
      <element name="value1.1"/>
      <element name="value1.2">
        <element name="1.2.1"/>
      </element>
      <element name="value1.3">
        <element name="value1.3.1"/>
      </element>
</opening>
```

using following code:

```
>>> a=open('file.xml').read()
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> s= BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(a)
>>> print s.prettify()
```

and I get following output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<opening name="value1">
 <element name="value1.1">
 </element>
 <element name="value1.2">
 </element>
 <element name="1.2.1">
 </element>
 <element name="value1.3">
 </element>
 <element name="value1.3.1">
 </element>
</opening>
```

Why does is shows all the element as child of opening tag ?
How do I parse this file properly?

I've tried using 
    s= BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup(a)
also but this also didn't work.

Comment: I confirmed your issue with BeautifulSoup3.  The problem appears to be fixed in BeautifulSoup4.  Install BeautifulSoup4.

Answer (score 1):

`BeautifulSoup` is primarily an `HTML` parser that tries it best to deal with mal-formed HTML. There are XML libraries out there such as `lxml` which I highly recommend - try that.

An example:

```
import lxml.etree

xml = """<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<opening name="value1" >
      <element name="value1.1"/>
      <element name="value1.2">
        <element name="1.2.1"/>
      </element>
      <element name="value1.3">
        <element name="value1.3.1"/>
      </element>
</opening>
"""

r = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
r.xpath('//element/@name')
# ['value1.1', 'value1.2', '1.2.1', 'value1.3', 'value1.3.1']
```

Comment: If you still want the functionality provided by BeautifulSoup then you can just specify that it use an xml parser instead ie. `BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml")` -- it requires `lxml` though.

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful Soup 3 requires a special argument to get tags to close properly. You need the selfClosingTags argument to the BeautifulStoneSoup constructor. Use something like:

```
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(markup, selfClosingTags=['element'])
```